# Why is byte stuffing preferred to use with PPP?

Tags: networking, ppp

I read that PPP can use both bit and byte stuffing, but I can't think of any reason why byte stuffing is preffered. Can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copied from some text book

```
PPP was clearly designed to be implemented in software, not in hardware as
HDLC nearly always is. With a software implementation, working entirely
with bytes is much simpler than working with individual bits. In addition,
PPP was designed to be used with modems, and modems accept and transmit
data in units of 1 byte, not 1 bit.
```